# Modify instance variables which are parameters inside method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to pass instance variables to a method, which then modifies them. This is because I have the same logic for different instance variables. Is this possible? I haven't got it working.

```
class A
    def update_ivar()
        update(@ivar)
    end
    
    def update(var)
       var = 1
    end
    
    def print_ivar()
        puts @ivar
        puts @ivar == nil
    end
end

a = A.new
a.update_ivar()
a.print_ivar()
```

Output

```
true
```

Comment: You don't need to pass instance variable. The very purpose of instance variable is use inside the methods which are inside the class.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I have the same logic for different instance vars, should I just create nearly identical methods were the only difference is the instance var being modified?

Comment: If you have the same logic for multiple pieces of data, then it is an indicator you need an `Array`, a `Hash`, or a similar container structure. You _could_ do the same with instance variables, passing their name and looking them up using introspection, but that is an anti-pattern (less readable, less safe, and probably also less fast).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`instance_variable_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) like this:

```
class A
  def update_ivar
    update(:@ivar) # Note the symbolized name here, it is not the variable itself
  end

 def update(var_name)
   instance_variable_set(var_name, 1)
 end

 def print_ivar
   puts @ivar
   puts @ivar == nil
 end
end

a = A.new
a.update_ivar  
a.print_ivar   
#=> 1
#=> false
```

I personally wouldn't like such a pattern because it leads to hard to read and understand code. But is it a code smell? That certainly depends on your application and your exact use case.